# How to disable hooks in feathers

Tags: hook, feathersjs

I'm pretty new to feathers. Is there a way I can temporarily disable a feathers common hook? If no, can I call a hook inside a hook? or how do I create a conditional hook?

use case: I want to disable the populate common hook for a certain service.find operation and only that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can call other `common-hooks` inside a hook. They are pre-made functions and commonly used so the feathers team made them for you. You can create your own if you want, to suit your needs.

You can do something like this.

```
  unless(
    hook => (falsy condition here),
    populate({ schema: yourSchema }),
  )
```

There are many ways to do it.